# How to keep PlotLegend expressions on top of each others even when placed at Bottom?

Tags: plotting, legending

Version 9.

When writing

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[TraditionalForm /@ {Sin[x], Cos[x]}, Right]]
```

The result is

[image]

Now I'd like to put the legend below the plot, but at the same time keep them looking the same way. i.e. `sin(x)` on top and `cos(x)` below. I do not want them to flatten. But when I do

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[TraditionalForm /@ {Sin[x], Cos[x]}, Bottom]]
```

The result is

[image]

I can't use Grid or such to format these myself in the way I like them, since if I do, then `PlotLegend` will not see them any more. i.e. I can't just write something like

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[ Column[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}], Bottom]]
```

[image]

Any one knows of a trick to do this? I looked at options for PlotLegend but do not see anything right away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend["Expressions", LegendLayout -> "Column"], Bottom]]
```

[image]

**Update:** the following (which does not explicitly use `LineLegend` in the input) also gives the same picture:

```
 Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends ->  Placed[TraditionalForm /@ {Sin[x], Cos[x]}, Bottom]] /. 
   (LegendLayout -> _) :> LegendLayout -> "Column"
```

If you are certain that the strings `"Row"` and `"Column"` appear only in connection with legend layout in your plot, you can use the simpler replacement rule `"Row" -> "Column"`.